# Search Functionality

Tags: django

django, this search functionality is working but data is not displaying on the template.
I'm beginner in django. Please help me

view.py:

```
def search(request):
    search_machinename = request.GET.get('q')
    if (search_machinename is not None) and search_machinename:
        machinename = Item.objects.filter(QuerySet(machinename__icontains=search_machinename) | 
        QuerySet(operationno__icontains=search_machinename))
        if not machinename:
            machinename = Item.objects.all()

    context = {'machinename': machinename}

    return render(request, 'usermaster/item-form.html', context)
```

Template file:
item-form.html:
[Webpage of this template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXXAJ.png)

```
<form action="{{url.search}}" method='get' value='{{ request.get.q }}' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{fields}}

    <input type="text" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <table>
        {% for data in machinename %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ data.machine_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.operation_no }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

code is working but it is not displaying on webpage

Comment: Is `QuerySet` an alias for `Q`?
Could you please show us your imports too?

Comment: sorry, it;s a Q.

Comment: Can you share your `models.py` and `urls.py` for your app too?

Comment: model - class Item(models.Model):
   def __str__(self):
      return self.machine_name
   machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   operation_no = models.IntegerField()

Comment: urls.py - path('search',views.search,name='search'),

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled your model field names, `operationno__icontains` and `machinename__icontains` in Queryset or Q.
Change them like this:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Item
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    search_machine_name = request.GET.get('q')
    context = {}
    if (search_machine_name is not None) and search_machine_name:
        machine_name = Item.objects.filter(Q(machine_name__icontains=search_machine_name) | 
        Q(operation_no__icontains=search_machine_name))
        if not machine_name:
            machine_name = Item.objects.all()

        context['machine_name'] = machine_name

    return render(request, 'usermaster/item-form.html', context)
```

```
# templates/usermaster/item-form.html
<form action="{{url.search}}" method='get' value='{{ request.get.q }}' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{fields}}

    <input type="text" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <table>
        {% for data in machine_name %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ data.machine_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ data.operation_no }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    operation_no = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self): 
        return self.machine_name
```

```
# Project urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(('<your_app_name>.urls', 'url'), namespace='url')),
]
```

```
# your app urls.py
from .views import search
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('search', search, name='search')
]
```

Comment: sir, It is not working yet.

Comment: Does it show any errors? Do you have any data in your database?

Comment: It is not showing any errors

Comment: I will add other files for you but this is working for me.

Comment: This is the output showing on the terminal:                                     [01/Jan/2022 15:37:54] "GET /machine/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=ErYX2egyRhN6uAnspquRTIcWmfV3S9SsVELcG5M1Ru8qDiPtAv4ZIcQqwZqncO4n&q=kar HTTP/1.1" 200 2405

Comment: By the way, Why are you trying to check contains in `operation_no` field? Isn't it supposed to be an integer? The part that says: `operation_no__icontains=search_machine_name`

Comment: so what do i do now

Comment: Do you have any item in your database which contains `kar` in its `machine_name` field?

Comment: yes, it is a machine name which is stored in database

Comment: It is really weird :( Sorry I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: It must display machine name and operation number in the form of table after search. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: Do you have any different search functionality code in Django. If you have please give that.

Comment: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-search/